# How to convert python logging level name to integer code

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

As of Python 3.2, `logging.Logger.setLevel` accepts a string level such as 'INFO' instead of the corresponding integer constant. This is very handy except that you can't compare the levels numerically that way and most other logging methods accept integers only. How do I convert a level string to a numerical level using the functions provided by the `logging` package? Specifically, I would like something that does this:

```
>>> logging.???('INFO') == logging.INFO
True
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use:

```
import logging
logging.getLevelName('INFO')
```

Comment: Past 3.4.2, this is by far the simplest way to do it

Comment: I absolutely can't recommend to use `logging.getLevelName()`. The function has a messed up interface, and you're never sure whether a `str` or an `int` is returned. Even with `str`, you can't tell whether the string represents a real level (like "INFO") or an invalid value (like "level info"). No value checking, no type checking -> don't use it.

Comment: Python 3.11 introduced `getLevelNamesMapping` https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLevelNamesMapping which is a mapping from string to a level name in Logging Levels https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels (int). This should clarify semantics.

Answer (score 44):

How about using something like

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> getattr(logging, 'INFO')
20
>>> getattr(logging, 'DEBUG')
10
>>> getattr(logging, 'ERROR')
40
>>>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A query without modifying the state of any logger.

Comment: @ronkov's solution seems to be more robust

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of attributes in the `logging` module that allow this functionality. They are prefixed with an underscore, implying privacy, so using them is not a good idea. However:

At the highest level, there is `_checkLevel`, which takes a level that is either a string or an integer and either returns the corresponding *existing* level or raises a `ValueError`.

`_checkLevel` wraps the dictionary `_nameToLevel`, which contains all the registered levels (and gets updated by `addLevelName`).

There is an additional member called `_levelToName`, which contains the reverse mapping. It is publicly accessible via the `getLevelName` method.